# Meteor with typescript run with Unknown absolute import path

Tags: meteor, typescript

I used `meteor-typescript-compiler` (https://github.com/meteor-typescript/meteor-typescript-compiler) for my new project. For testing purpose, I created fresh Meteor project and put only one file `main.ts` to it

```
/// <reference path="./typings/definitions/meteor.d.ts" />
console.log ('added to stack');
Meteor.methods({
  'test': function() {
     console.log('from main');
  }
});
```

Then, I added 2 packages

```
meteor add meteortypescript:compiler
meteor add systemjs:systemjs
```

And download the definition files from https://github.com/meteor-typescript/meteor-typescript-libs and put into the `typings` folder

When triggering `meteor run`, I got the exception

```
main.ts (3, 1): Cannot compile namespaces when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.
main.ts (3, 1): Cannot compile namespaces when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.
=> Errors prevented startup:                  

   While processing files with meteortypescript:compiler (for target web.browser):
   <anonymous>: Unknown absolute import path /typings/definitions/meteor.d.ts
```

My Visual Studio Code can see the reference path and does not complain anything about that. What can I do to make this simple configuration work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot compile namespaces when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided

Since the `meteor.d.ts` file uses namespaces you should not have `--isolatedModules` compiler flag set. Add a tsconfig.json if there isn't one already and have this option set to false.

Comment: Thanks @basarat. I can compile the project now, but now I have another issue regarding to generated javascript file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991506/meteor-methods-cannot-be-added-during-run-time-when-using-typescript-with-system