# Meteor methods cannot be added during run time when using typescript with SystemJs

Tags: meteor, typescript

I used `meteor-typescript-compiler` (https://github.com/meteor-typescript/meteor-typescript-compiler) for my new project. After setting up the project and getting the great help from `@basarat`, I was able to let the project startup normally. However, look like the generated js file is not triggered during the time server is executed, thus all the Meteor methods are not triggered and added to Meteor.

```
/// <reference path="../typings/definitions/meteor.d.ts" />


export class App {
  constructor() {
  }
}

Meteor.startup(function() {
   console.log ('added to stack');
});

Meteor.methods({
  'test': function() {
     console.log('from new 2');
  }
});
```

When starting up the meteor server, the generated js file is

```
(function(){

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                                     //
// server/main.js                                                      //
//                                                                     //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                                                       //
/// <reference path="../typings/definitions/meteor.d.ts" />            // 1
System.register("server/main", [], function(exports_1) {               //
    var App;                                                           //
    return {                                                           //
        setters:[],                                                    //
        execute: function() {                                          //
            App = (function () {                                       //
                function App() {                                       //
                }                                                      //
                return App;                                            //
            })();                                                      //
            exports_1("App", App);                                     //
            Meteor.startup(function () {                               //
                console.log('added to stack');                         //
            });                                                        //
            Meteor.methods({                                           //
                'test': function () {                                  //
                    console.log('from new 2');                         //
                }                                                      //
            });                                                        //
        }                                                              //
    }                                                                  //
});                                                                    //
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map                                       //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}).call(this);

//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

And this is my `tsconfig.json` (I also added the .tsconfig to the root folder based on the `meteor-typescript-compiler` 's guidance)

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "typings"
    ]
}
```

The line `added to stack` is not shown when server is running (I added package `systemjs:systemjs` into meteor). For the testing purpose, I uploaded the project into https://github.com/bubuzzz/new1.git

Answer (score 1):

> thus all the Meteor methods are not triggered and added to Meteor.

You need to load the main.js file as a *dependency*. i.e someone needs to call the function that is registered against `server/main` (in `System.register("server/main", [], function(exports_1) {`)

Reading the docs : https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs#browser I seems you need

```
System.import('server/main.js');
```

Comment: This is odd. So, do I have to include manually all compiled js file as the dependencies,  while the main purpose of the typescript meteor compiler there is to hide all the js file from the developer 's view. Also, the file is on the server side, which is not available for the browser, i guess. Is there any way to stop the compiler from wrapping the whole generated js to the `System.register`. I tried several options for the `tsconfig.json` but look like it does not affect the transpilation way. Please have a look at my updated question

Comment: `So, do I have to include manually all compiled js file as the dependencies` no. Just the main one. The main one will then bring in its dependencies automatically and so on